# Can and should a Maven POM specify if it requires Maven 3 or newer?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I am currently doing some cleanup of Java projects which use Maven, and use NetBeans IDE to 'debug' problems in the POM. I have set Maven 3.0.4 in the IDE as the Maven version, but other developers or our Continuous Intgeration system might have different settings.

Is it possible to 'enforce' a specific Maven version directly in the POM (for example by using a Maven 3 specific element)?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes you can and you should. Some Maven plugins requires Maven 3 or newer.

Use the maven-enforcer-plugin by adding the following to your `pom.xml`:

```xml
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <inherited>true</inherited>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.4.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>enforce-maven-version</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <rules>
                <requireMavenVersion>
                  <version>3.8.5</version>
                </requireMavenVersion>                
              </rules>
              <fail>true</fail>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
       </executions>
     </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 11):

Another option is to use the prerequisites element in the pom, for example:

```
<project>
   ...
   <prerequisites>
       <maven>3.0.0</maven>
   </prerequisites>
   ...
</project>
```

As noted [Michal Kalinowski's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10511594/1033422) - this simple approach does not work so well for children projects.

For a summary of which approach will work best for you, see here: [enforcing maven 3 - when to use maven enforcer plugin? when to use pom prerequisites element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18055009/enforcing-maven-3-when-to-use-maven-enforcer-plugin-when-to-use-pom-prerequis)

Answer (score 7):

The best thing you can do is to use Enforcer plugin. Here's an example:
http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireMavenVersion.html

There is no out-of-the-box method in Maven itself for doing this. There is actually `prerequisites` tag but it doesn't work well, because children don't inherit it.

Comment: Be mindful of including links as they can die... And note there was already another answer that includes the relevant snippet.