# enforcing maven 3 - when to use maven enforcer plugin? when to use pom prerequisites element?

Tags: java, maven

The two main approaches for enforcing maven 3 seem to be:

- maven-enforcer-plugin, and
- pom.xml `<prerequisites>` element.

The best approach to uses seems to depend on a few different factors. This question is to help people decide which approach makes the most sense for them.

**Question**: What types of project structures are best suited to maven-enforcer-plugin and what types of project structure are best suited to pom prerequisites.

---

### Maven Enforcer Plugin Example

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <inherited>true</inherited>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>enforce-maven-3</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <rules>
                <requireMavenVersion>
                  <version>3.0.5</version>
                </requireMavenVersion>                
              </rules>
              <fail>true</fail>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
       </executions>
     </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

### Maven POM Prerequisites Example

```
<project>
   ...
   <prerequisites>
       <maven>3.0.5</maven>
   </prerequisites>
   ...
</project>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Prerequisites are deprecated, and you should use the enforcer plugin. [MNG-5297](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5297) requests a documentation update to clarify this.

The `maven-enforcer-plugin` FAQ [explains the difference](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/faq.html):

> Why can't I just use the prerequisites tag in the pom?
>
> The prerequisites tag was designed to be used by tools like plugins. It will work for regular projects, but it isn't inherited to their children. If it is set in a parent reactor, then Maven will do the check. **However if one of the children are built, the check is not performed.** The enforcer plugin is designed to allow centralized control over the build environment from a single "super-pom", and to allow greater flexibility in version specification by supporting ranges.

In addition, note that [prerequisites do not work with Maven 3](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-4840).

Comment: The [JIRA](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-4840) shows that prerequisites should work for maven 3.0.2+

Comment: You're right, there was a fix there, but they appear to be [broken again in 3.1](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-5501).

Comment: You should update your answer based on the latest content of MNG-5297: prerequisites are not deprecated, they're for a different purpose than the enforcer plugin.

Answer (score 2):

The Maven `pom prerequisites` approach may be more appropriate for smaller, simpler projects.  This approach will be lighter weight as it will not require the `maven-enforcer-plugin` to be downloaded.

The `maven-enforcer-plugin` approach may be more suitable if you have children projects that you wish to inherit the maven 3 requirement from the parent.  `pom prerequisites` is not inherited by children projects.